# How we can create a custom Vertical Gauge by using image in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, gauge

I am new to the SwiftUI, and i am trying to design a speedometer of a vehicle using SwiftUI, for that i have checked in various solutions, but all of them were of either circular or linear horizontal, but i need it fully customized.

Please find the attachment to clarify what thing i am going to create.
[image]

**ContentView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct SpeedometerGaugeStyle: GaugeStyle {
   private var numberOfIterations = 40
   private var purpleGradient = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors:
                                                                [ Color.red,
                                                                  Color.green,
                                                                  Color.blue
                                                                ]),
                                            startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
   func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
      VStack {
          ForEach((1...20), id: \.self) { index in
              RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 10))
                  .frame(width: (Double(100 - ( index * 2 )) ), height: 10)
                  .foregroundStyle(ColorGradient.putIndex(index: index))
          }
      }
  }



  struct ColorGradient  {
    
    static func putIndex(index : Int) -> LinearGradient {
        
        switch index {
        case 0...4:
            return LinearGradient(colors: [
                Color.red,
                Color.red.opacity(0.7),
                Color.red.opacity(0.6),
                Color.red.opacity(0.5)
            ],
            startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top)
        case 4...8:
            return LinearGradient(colors: [
                Color.orange,
                Color.orange.opacity(0.7),
                Color.orange.opacity(0.6),
                Color.orange.opacity(0.5)
            ],
            startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top)
            
        case 8...16:
            return LinearGradient(colors: [
                Color.cyan,
                Color.cyan.opacity(0.7),
                Color.cyan.opacity(0.6),
                Color.cyan.opacity(0.5)
            ],
            startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top)
        default:
            return LinearGradient(colors: [
                Color.green,
                Color.green.opacity(0.8),
                Color.green.opacity(0.9),
                Color.green.opacity(1.0)
            ],
            startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top)
       }
     }
   }
 }


struct CustomGaugeView: View {

  @State private var currentSpeed = 45.0
  @State private var animateGradient = false

  var body: some View {
      VStack {
          Gauge(value: currentSpeed, in: 0...160) {
              Text(currentSpeed.debugDescription)
          } currentValueLabel: {
              Text("\(currentSpeed.formatted(.number))")
                  .foregroundColor(Color.white)
          }
          .gaugeStyle(SpeedometerGaugeStyle())
          .frame(width: 200, height: 300)
        
          Spacer()
        
          Slider(value: $currentSpeed, in: 0...160) {
              EmptyView()
          }
          Spacer()
      }
   }
 }
```

**Main**

```
  @main
  struct Speedometer_DemoApp: App {
   var body: some Scene {
      WindowGroup {
          CustomGaugeView()
            .previewDisplayName("CustomGaugeView")
      }
    }
  }
```

Can anyone help me on this to obtain this type of gauge using SwiftUI?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is your specific question? You showed some code, but you haven't mentioned what the problem is with it.

Comment: I need to create this type of Gauge like speedometer by using this attached image 
and, i have created it with rectangle in the current code.

Comment: You still haven't said what the specific problem is.

Comment: Let me explain, @jnpdx 
Can you help me to create similar functionality like a speedometer in motorcycle?
Also i need the layout like image attched

Comment: No, that question is far to general/vauge for this site. See [ask]

Comment: Look into `mask` it is much simpler to `mask` than try to calculate all the colors manually

Comment: @loremipsum kindly elaborate

Comment: I am not going to make it for you, im just giving you a search term so you can do research, there are several posts on the subject on SO and the web in general. If you narrow down your issue to something specific Ill be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need the configuration.value to make it work.

```
struct SpeedometerGaugeStyle: GaugeStyle {
private var numberOfIterations = 20

private var purpleGradient = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors:
                                                                [ Color.red,
                                                                  Color.green,
                                                                  Color.blue
                                                                ]),
                                            startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)


func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach((0... numberOfIterations).reversed(), id: \.self) { index in
                   RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 10))
                       .frame(width: (Double(100 + ( index * 2 )) ), height: 5)
                       .foregroundStyle(ColorGradient.putIndex(index: index))
                       .opacity((configuration.value * numberOfIterations) > Double(index) ? 1 : 0.3)
               }
           }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
  }
}
```

The alignment: .leading in the vstack pushes it to one side .trailing will switch it to the other.

I also switched the color gradient around to go from green to red

```
struct ColorGradient  {

static func putIndex(index : Int) -> LinearGradient {

    switch index {
    case 0...4:
        return LinearGradient(colors: [
            Color.green,
            Color.green.opacity(0.8),
            Color.green.opacity(0.9),
            Color.green.opacity(1.0)
        ],
                              startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top)

    case 4...8:
        return LinearGradient(colors: [
            Color.cyan,
            Color.cyan.opacity(0.7),
            Color.cyan.opacity(0.6),
            Color.cyan.opacity(0.5)
        ],
                              startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top)

    case 8...15:
        return LinearGradient(colors: [
            Color.orange,
            Color.orange.opacity(0.7),
            Color.orange.opacity(0.6),
            Color.orange.opacity(0.5)
        ],
                              startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top)
    default:
        return LinearGradient(colors: [
            Color.red,
            Color.red.opacity(0.7),
            Color.red.opacity(0.6),
            Color.red.opacity(0.5)
        ],
                              startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top)
    }
  }
}
```